# Turn based Android game using google play games services

Tags: google-app-engine, google-play-services

I want to develop a turn-based,multiplayer android game.Its very similar to chess.Is it possible to make entire game just by using google play games services(GPGS) ? ie, creating a game between 2 players,managing player moves,changing game states in database, all this can be done using GPGS? 
Also,is google-app-engine anyhow related to this ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Google Play Game Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/) can do all this for you. It supports leaderboards, cloud saving of progress, room based multiplayer lobby system, achievements and much more.

[Here's documentation for turn-based multiplayer game service](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/turnbasedMultiplayer)

Google app engine is hosting environment for your game, in cloud. However, you can only use Python, Go, Java and PHP to develop for it.